# silex loop one sql statement over another one

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine, twig, silex

I have to get team members by their groups from a database.

My Database looks like:

table team_groups:

- id
- name

table team_member:

- id
- name
- description
- imagepath
- team_group_id

I have an twig template where the team_members are shown by there groups like this:

```
<div class="row row-centered">
      <h3 class="text-center">{{team_group.name}}</h3>

      <div class="col-xs-6 col-centered col-fixed">
        <div class="item">
          <div class="team-member text-center">
            <span><img class="img-team" src="{{ app.request.basepath }}/img/team/{{team_member.imagepath}}"
                       alt="{{team_member.name}}"></span>

            <h3>{{team_member.name}}</h3>

            <p>{{team_member.description}}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-centered col-fixed">
        <div class="item">
          <div class="team-member text-center">
            <span><img class="img-team" src="{{ app.request.basepath }}/img/team/{{team_member.imagepath}}"
                       alt="{{team_member.name}}"></span>

            <h3>{{team_member.name}}</h3>

            <p>{{team_member.description}}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-centered col-fixed">
        <div class="item">
          <div class="team-member text-center">
            <span><img class="img-team" src="{{ app.request.basepath }}/img/team/{{team_member.imagepath}}"
                       alt="{{team_member.name}}"></span>

            <h3>{{team_member.name}}</h3>

            <p>{{team_member.description}}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

But I don't know how to loop the team_members over the team_groups in my controller.

I started like that:

```
$teamGroups = $app['db']->fetchAll('SELECT * team_groups');
$teamMembers = $app['db']->fetchAll('SELECT * team_members');
```

but don't know how to continue.

Please help

Comment: based on what you provided above for your database structure, there is nothing linking a member to a group.

Comment: sorry missed one column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh yeah twig is really nice...

I thought I have to link the objects in the controller, but now I simply wrote:

```
{% for teamGroup in teamGroups %}
      <div class="row row-centered">
        <h3 class="text-center">{{ teamGroup.name }}</h3>
        {% for teamMember in teamMembers %}
          {% if teamMember.team_group_id is same as(teamGroup.id) %}
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-centered col-fixed">
              <div class="item">
                <div class="team-member text-center">
            <span><img class="img-team" src="{{ app.request.basepath }}/img/team/{{ teamMember.image }}"
                       alt="{{ teamMember.name }}"></span>

                  <h3>{{ teamMember.name }}</h3>

                  <p>{{ teamMember.description }}</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
      </div>
    {% endfor %}
```

That did it for me :-)